# Using Sentry.NET in conjunction with log4net

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, sentry

I have a question regarding using Sentry.NET in conjunction with log4net.

I installed the [Sentry.Log4Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.Log4Net/) NuGet package and setup the config file according to [this example](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/master/samples/Sentry.Samples.Log4Net/app.config.)

In general, it works. The Log4net calls are reported to our Sentry account, according to the debug level I configured in the config file.
However, each Log call creates its own Sentry Event. I would've expected that Log4net calls create Sentry "Breadcrumbs".
Its not really useful to have hundreds of logging events reporting to the Sentry back end.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that at this time the Sentry log4net only raises events. If possible, I'd suggest changing to one of the logging libraries that support structured logging like Serilog.

The other logging integrations have such behavior where you have two log levels to configure. One to set the minimum level to create a breadcrumb, and another to send an event.

You could raise an issue on GitHub requesting this feature. Or even, contribute with a pull request to change [SentryAppender](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/master/src/Sentry.Log4Net/SentryAppender.cs) to behave like the [SerilogSink](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/master/src/Sentry.Serilog/SentrySink.cs), [NLog Target](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/master/src/Sentry.NLog/SentryTarget.cs) or the [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging integration](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/master/src/Sentry.Extensions.Logging/SentryLogger.cs).

Comment: An option to specify a second "breadcrumb" log level sounds like a good approach. I will consider extending the SentryAppender then. Thanks.

Comment: @Rev1.0 did you end up extending the SentryAppender?

Comment: @Marcel Indeed I did. I can post the implementation as a answer.

Comment: Would be nice to send changes to the upstream repo. It could become available to all users of the sdk

Answer (score 3):

In ended up creating my own SentryAppender with the option to provide a `MinimumBreadcrumbLevel`.

SentryAppender implementation:

```
public class SentryAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    private readonly Func<string, IDisposable> _initAction;
    private volatile IDisposable _sdkHandle;

    private readonly object _initSync = new object();

    internal static readonly SdkVersion NameAndVersion
        = typeof(SentryAppender).Assembly.GetNameAndVersion();

    private static readonly string ProtocolPackageName = NameAndVersion.Name;

    internal IHub Hub { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sentry DSN.
    /// </summary>
    public string Dsn { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Whether to send the Identity or not.
    /// </summary>
    public bool SendIdentity { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Environment to send in the event.
    /// </summary>
    public string Environment { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Minimum log level to be included in the breadcrumb.
    /// </summary>
    public Level MinimumBreadcrumbLevel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="SentryAppender"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public SentryAppender() : this(SentrySdk.Init, HubAdapter.Instance)
    { }

    internal SentryAppender(
        Func<string, IDisposable> initAction,
        IHub hubGetter)
    {
        Debug.Assert(initAction != null);
        Debug.Assert(hubGetter != null);

        _initAction = initAction;
        Hub = hubGetter;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Append log.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="loggingEvent">The event.</param>
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (loggingEvent == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!Hub.IsEnabled && _sdkHandle == null)
        {
            if (Dsn == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (_initSync)
            {
                if (_sdkHandle == null)
                {
                    _sdkHandle = _initAction(Dsn);
                    Debug.Assert(_sdkHandle != null);
                }
            }
        }

        // Either log a BreadCrumb or an Event
        if (MinimumBreadcrumbLevel < loggingEvent.Level)
        {
            var exception = loggingEvent.ExceptionObject ?? loggingEvent.MessageObject as Exception;
            var evt = new SentryEvent(exception)
            {
                Sdk =
                {
                    Name = Constants.SdkName,
                    Version = NameAndVersion.Version
                },
                Logger = loggingEvent.LoggerName,
                Level = loggingEvent.ToSentryLevel()
            };

            evt.Sdk.AddPackage(ProtocolPackageName, NameAndVersion.Version);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage))
            {
                evt.Message = loggingEvent.RenderedMessage;
            }

            evt.SetExtras(GetLoggingEventProperties(loggingEvent));

            if (SendIdentity && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggingEvent.Identity))
            {
                evt.User = new User
                {
                    Id = loggingEvent.Identity
                };
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Environment))
            {
                evt.Environment = Environment;
            }

            Hub.CaptureEvent(evt);
        }
        else
        {
            string message = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage) ? loggingEvent.RenderedMessage : "";
            string type = "";
            string category = loggingEvent.LoggerName;
            BreadcrumbLevel level = loggingEvent.ToBreadcrumbLevel();
            IDictionary<string, string> data = GetLoggingEventProperties(loggingEvent).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());

            Hub.AddBreadcrumb(message, category, type, data, level);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetLoggingEventProperties(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        var properties = loggingEvent.GetProperties();
        if (properties == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (var key in properties.GetKeys())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key)
                && !key.StartsWith("log4net:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var value = properties[key];
                if (value != null
                    && (!(value is string stringValue) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue)))
                {
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(key, value);
                }
            }
        }

        var locInfo = loggingEvent.LocationInformation;
        if (locInfo != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locInfo.ClassName))
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(nameof(locInfo.ClassName), locInfo.ClassName);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locInfo.FileName))
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(nameof(locInfo.FileName), locInfo.FileName);
            }

            if (int.TryParse(locInfo.LineNumber, out var lineNumber) && lineNumber != 0)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(nameof(locInfo.LineNumber), lineNumber);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locInfo.MethodName))
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(nameof(locInfo.MethodName), locInfo.MethodName);
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggingEvent.ThreadName))
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(nameof(loggingEvent.ThreadName), loggingEvent.ThreadName);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggingEvent.Domain))
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(nameof(loggingEvent.Domain), loggingEvent.Domain);
        }

        if (loggingEvent.Level != null)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>("log4net-level", loggingEvent.Level.Name);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes the SDK if initialized.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnClose()
    {
        base.OnClose();

        _sdkHandle?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Helper class for mapping the different log levels:

```
internal static class LevelMapping
{
    public static SentryLevel? ToSentryLevel(this LoggingEvent loggingLevel)
    {
        switch (loggingLevel.Level)
        {
            case var l when l == Level.Fatal
                            || l == Level.Emergency
                            || l == Level.All:
                return SentryLevel.Fatal;
            case var l when l == Level.Alert
                            || l == Level.Critical
                            || l == Level.Severe
                            || l == Level.Error:
                return SentryLevel.Error;
            case var l when l == Level.Warn:
                return SentryLevel.Warning;
            case var l when l == Level.Notice
                            || l == Level.Info:
                return SentryLevel.Info;
            case var l when l == Level.Debug
                            || l == Level.Verbose
                            || l == Level.Trace
                            || l == Level.Finer
                            || l == Level.Finest
                            || l == Level.Fine:
                return SentryLevel.Debug;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static BreadcrumbLevel ToBreadcrumbLevel(this LoggingEvent loggingLevel) {
        switch (loggingLevel.Level) {
            case var l when l == Level.Fatal
                            || l == Level.Emergency
                            || l == Level.All:
                return BreadcrumbLevel.Critical;
            case var l when l == Level.Alert
                            || l == Level.Critical
                            || l == Level.Severe
                            || l == Level.Error:
                return BreadcrumbLevel.Error;
            case var l when l == Level.Warn:
                return BreadcrumbLevel.Warning;
            case var l when l == Level.Notice
                            || l == Level.Info:
                return BreadcrumbLevel.Info;
            case var l when l == Level.Debug
                            || l == Level.Verbose
                            || l == Level.Trace
                            || l == Level.Finer
                            || l == Level.Finest
                            || l == Level.Fine:
                return BreadcrumbLevel.Debug;
        }

        return BreadcrumbLevel.Debug;
    }
}
```

log4net.config example:

```xml
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="SentryAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="SentryAppender" type="YourNamespace.SentryAppender">
    <!-- If we initialize the SDK via code (SentrySdk.Init), DSN is not required here. -->
    <!-- <Dsn value="" /> -->
    <!-- Level options: ALL DEBUG INFO WARN ERROR FATAL OFF -->
    <threshold value="DEBUG" />
    <!-- Everything below or equal to this level will be recorded as a Sentry "breadcrumb" -->
    <MinimumBreadcrumbLevel value="WARN" />
  </appender>
</log4net>
```